# wget not displaying output through Runtime.getRuntime.exec(String[] commandArray)

Tags: java, linux, wget

I have a java program to monitor URL status and check ssl certificate expiry date for every web based application for a certain corporate entity. The jar file is deployed in a production environment. I have used **javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection** and **java.security.cert.X509Certificate** however they do not seem to work for all URLs due to some VPN or intranet issue, however it is possible to check the status of the URL by running shell commands in the production server itself. Since **openssl** is not installed I get by using

> curl -Iks -w "RESPONSE_CODE: %{http_code}\nRESPONSE_TIME: %{time_total}\n" https://www.google.com | egrep 'HTTP|RESPONSE'

the response

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>
> RESPONSE_CODE: 200
>
> RESPONSE_TIME: 0.293

but this also doesn't work for all websites, hence after some trial and error I started using

> time -p wget --spider --connect-timeout=20 --read-timeout=50 --no-check-certificate --server-response --quiet https://www.google.com

the response,

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>
> Date: Fri, 08 Jan 2016 17:40:07 GMT
>
> Expires: -1
>
> Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
>
> Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
>
> P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See https://www.google.com/support/accounts/answer/151657?hl=en for more info."
>
> Server: gws
>
> X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
>
> X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
>
> Set-Cookie: NID=75=Uo1kdhbBu-ZPh5mF8kYXwb-Zi-OrGCL4qk_T0eHAbrmiwvpUN1iq56D2mvgg_nN3HIadVBUe2u90a_Lk54UOXfMKHTAq2qCtNaud_cjKCogolWwP3PtX1Hm_L56uQV28NFJNRpUwZ57oWQ; expires=Sat, 09-Jul-2016 17:40:07 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly
>
> Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic,p=1
>
> Alt-Svc: quic="www.google.com:443"; ma=600; v="30,29,28,27,26,25",quic=":443"; ma=600; v="30,29,28,27,26,25"
>
> Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>
> Accept-Ranges: none
>
> Vary: Accept-Encoding
>
> real 0.58
>
> user 0.27
>
> sys 0.01

the test program is given below along with the output, however **wget** doesn't seem to display the result, although it is successfully executed; while a similar program with **curl** command displays the result.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RunProcessWGET {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            Process process = null;
            Scanner scanner = null;
            int lineCount = 0;
            int exitValue = 0;
            String[] commandUnix = {"/bin/sh",
                "-c",
                "time -p wget --spider --connect-timeout=20 --read-timeout=50 --no-check-certificate --server-response --quiet \""
                +args[0]+"\""};
            try {
                    process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandUnix);
                    scanner = new Scanner(process.getInputStream());
                    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                            ++lineCount;
                            System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
                    }
                    System.out.println("No. of Lines: "+lineCount);
                    process.waitFor();
                    exitValue = process.exitValue();
                    System.out.println((exitValue == 0?
                            "Operation Successful with exit code 0" : ("Operation Failed with exit code "+exitValue)));
                    if(exitValue != 0) {
                            scanner = new Scanner(process.getErrorStream());
                            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                                    System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
                            }
                    }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

      }

}
```

the output on running

> java RunProcessWGET www.google.com

is

> No. of Lines: 0
>
> Operation Successful with exit code 0

I prefer to use java to shell scripts. Is there any problem with the code, or with the way the command works or the environment. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

---

**NOTE:** This is only a sample program to check the output of the code. The actual code is a part of a larger package. Environment is, `Oracle Solaris 10 1/13 s10s_u11wos_24a SPARC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--server-response` option of wget write to stderror then you should redirect stderror in order to get it thought `getInputStream()`.

This can be achieved using [redirectErrorStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectErrorStream-boolean-) :

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(commandUnix);
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
process = builder.start();
scanner = new Scanner(process.getInputStream());
```

Answer (score 0):

Also I overlooked another simple solution: appending **`2>&1`** to the command.

```
String[] commandUnix = {"/bin/sh",
                "-c",
                "time -p wget --spider --connect-timeout=20 --read-timeout=50 --no-check-certificate --server-response --quiet \""
                +args[0]+"\" 2>&1"};
```

Basically does the same thing, redirects **`stderr`** to **`stdout`**.